# "Sorry Michael" in Ukrainian slang

Tags: сленг

Do people in Ukraine, especially Kyiv, sometimes say "Sorry, Michael" instead of "sorry"? Supposedly, this expression comes from some movie?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? how does it sound?

Comment: They don't unless the one they are apologizing to is actually Michael. And then it's not slang at all :-)

Comment: I've never encountered such a slang neither in English nor in Ukrainian.

Comment: @P. Vowk♦ that's just it. They say literally "sorry Michael" in English instead of "oops sorry".

Comment: @Yola maybe it's not strict slang, but just something people say?

Comment: @user1985 I've never heard anything like this either? Was it one time that you heard sth like this, or was it multiple times people saying the same thing?

Comment: @P. Vowk♦ one time, from a girl, maybe she said her ex's name instead of mine xD But it sounded smoothly and casually and she said that's how people said it in Ukraine, so I'm not sure. Also people don't actually say "sorry [name]" in normal conversation either, it's just "sorry" when it's something small like an accidental poke.

Comment: @user1985 it might be some subculture thing. Like people who watch the same US movie and then start saying something from that movie. I'll ask a couple of people about it and let you know.

Comment: @P. Vowk♦ You might be right. She watched and still watches a lot of American sitcoms, shows, movies etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to be about a very localized (sub-)culture, not about the language itself. The phrase *"sorry, Michael"* is in English.

Comment: @bytebuster it's hard to define, what's Ukrainian language, and what's not. The only problem I see here is that we don't know whether this girl is a Russian or Ukrainian speaker.

Comment: Hmm. So we don't know what language it is about, and what SE site it is eligible for. Nice. What word is more Ukrainian, "sorry" or "Michael"? :-)

Comment: Some people in Ukraine do say "Sorry Michael" (at least in the western part where I'm from). Also, I've stumbled upon a recent article on a [Ukrainian website](https://znaj.ua/capital/225942-sori-maykl-eto-biznes-kiyani-stali-svidkami-chudotvornogo-zcilennya-beznadiyno-hvoroji-video) where the phrase is used in the title (in Russian). Personally, I think the Vovochka joke could be the origin here.

Answer (score 6):

It's some rarely-used meme. Despite living in Kyiv, I've never heard it before. Searching through Internet shows few Russian-language references (though it doesn't mean that Ukrainian-speaking people don't use it; also the area of this meme is unclear for me: either it's used in Ukraine only, or in larger area like ex-USSR).

The full phrase seems to sound like:

> Sorry, Michael, [it's] just business.

I've found two versions about it's origin:

1. It's a distorted phrase from [The Godfather (1972)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather) movie:

   > [It's not personal, Sonny. It's strictly business.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Godfather)

   (which might sound like “Sorry, Sonny, it's just business” in some  localizations). Despite this phrase is directed to Sonny, not to Michael — [Michael Corleone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Corleone) is actually the one who says it — but it got strongly associated to Michael.

   Source: [this discussion](https://w1ndg1rl.livejournal.com/399696.html).

   (Similar phrase also seems to [appear in The Godfather videogame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erYybUiE0gk).)
2. It's from one of anecdotes about Vovochka. Vovochka is a [Little Johny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Johnny)-like character of anecdotes, popular since the Soviet era. Some of these anecdotes are political and mock specific-day realities (though often such anecdotes outlive their context and get new names/references/etc when the original context becomes outdated), other are just about human relationships.

   The specific anecdote is:

   > (Somewhere in USSR, Russia or etc during lesson in school.)
   >   Teacher: “Who is the most popular person?”
   >   Vovochka: “[Michael Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jackson)!”
   >   Teacher: “No, you're wrong. It's…” — teacher voices the name of a that-day official authority ([Brezhnev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev), [Putin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin) or etc) and continues: “Vovochka, you get the lowest mark!”
   >
   > The next day…
   >   Teacher: “Who is the most popular person?”
   >   Vovochka: “Michael Jackson!”
   >   Teacher: “No, you're wrong. You get the lowest mark again!”
   >
   > The next day…
   >   Teacher: “Who is the most popular person?”
   >   Vovochka voices a name of that-time authority.
   >   Teacher: “Excellent! You get the highest mark!”
   >   Vovochka (stealthily taking Michael Jackson's portrait from his schoolbag and looking onto it with great regret: “Sorry, Michael, it's just business…”

   Source: [this blog item](https://users.livejournal.com/-vector-/61606.html).

Which one of these versions is correct (and maybe none of them, the meme might come from another movie or another source) — I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely it is a reference to the first episode of Black Mirror, where the UK PM had to f**k a pig so the villain would let the Princess go. And when eventually all the strives to find the villain/princess failed, one of the other ministers said to the PM "sorry, Michael, but you have to do it". Although it might very well not be the case )))

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't think that's the origin of the phrase. I've heard it way before the Black Mirror episode came out. The version from Vovochka joke (as cited by Sasha) seems the most probable to me.